# Oracle manual fail -- demo of package using "Accessible By" clause throws exception

Tags: oracle, package

I'm following along with the Oracle manual here:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/packages.htm#LNPLS00906

Section 10-8 demonstrates creation of a package using the "Accessible By" clause, however, the code fails with an exception.  Anyone know why?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE helper
  AUTHID DEFINER
  ACCESSIBLE BY (api)
IS
  PROCEDURE h1;
  PROCEDURE h2;
END;
```

Error(4,3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ACCESSIBLE" when expecting one of the following:     is as

Comment: what version of oracle are you running?

Comment: Have you created a package named `API` ?  The syntax seems to be ok, please see this demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5bfbe0c15ec76b672c9f8ed476adb26b  (but the package API must be created first).